# Can not execute delete operation by using deleteBy custom method in spring data repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

When I try to delete data from my service class using deleteBy() custom method in spring data repository it gives following error.

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call

I tried with making method and service class @Transactional. Then autowire members get null. Those were initialize without @Transactional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load all the data that need to be deleted.
getBYId(id);
And use that collection to execute deleteAll() operation.
That solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the object first

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, but after I annotated only the method with `@Transactional`, it worked.

```
@Repository()
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Transactional
    fun deleteAllByCpf(cpf: String)
}
```

In my case, I'm using Springboot with Kotlin.

Comment: This would be a nice way Instead of loading the entities to delete as mentioned in other answers.